# i can't log into my cpanel and keep asking me for log in

Tags: session, logging, cpanel

I am having a very hard time logging into my cpanel . Everytime when I log in to the cpanel , it ask me for username and password . After entering credentials ,it shows the message "successfully logged in " . Right after a sec later , it prompts me for login box to enter . It repeats several times results in getting stucked in that steps . I didn't find any proper solution in Cpanel support forums and everyone ended up without having any solutions ..

Although , It might be quite silly to ask that of question here but i am having actually hard time searching for solutions .

Anyone has encountered this kind of prob before , pls let me know how to solve .. 
Thanks

Comment: try different computer?

Comment: i tried different OS , different Browser . It didn't work at all

Answer (score 0):

I've got the solution to this question . The reason is I'm stupidly enter the URL liked cpanel.mydomain.com . That's the reason why it is not working . Cuz sometimes it do not allow you to directly access the cpanel . So I have to type mydomain.com/cpanel . That's simply solved my difficult question